# Test a value returned from hook that is set by firebase auth listener

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hi I'm a bit lost on how to test a hook. I have a hook `useFirebase` that returns `{ user, loginToFirebase }`

1. `user` is the logged in user object
2. `loginToFirebase` is a method that can be called to authenticate a user. This method doesnt return anything by design. Instead when the user logs in, an `onAuthStateChanged` listener gets invoked by firebase and inside this listener I set the `user` to the hooks state.

```js
function loginToFirebase(email: string, password: string): void {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
        console.log("Wrong password.");
      } else {
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
    });
}

function useFirebase() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null);

  !firebase.apps.length && firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  useEffect(
    () =>
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        user && setUser(user);
      }),
    []
  );

  return {
    user,
    loginToFirebase,
    addWordToFirebase,
    getAllWords,
    logout
  };
}
```

Now Im trying to write a test for this but Im not sure what is the correct way. This is what I currently have

```js
  test("Should have user user on successful login", done => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFirebase());
    act(() => {
      result.current.loginToFirebase("test@gmail.com", "test");
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(result.current.user);
      done();
    }, 2000);
  });
```

Technically this works with warnings `Warning: An update to TestHook inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`. 
What is the proper way to test this scenario? Should I mock everything or is there another way to wait before asserting for the user object?

[This is the actual code.](https://github.com/blessenm/mein-woerterbuch/blob/master/src/hooks/useFirebase.ts)